# Cannot invoke Repo.save(Object) because this.Repo is null

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, repository

I can't understand why the error occurs. It seems that there is a dependency between the fields, but the program gives negative feedback.
**MAIN**

```
package com.example.botv2;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Botv2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws TelegramApiException, IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(Botv2Application.class, args);
        var tg = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
        var config = new Properties();
        try (var app = Botv2Application.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties")) {
            config.load(app);
        }
        var actions = Map.of(
                "/start", new InfoAction(
                        List.of(
                                "/start - Команды бота",
                                "/echo - Ввод данных для команды",
                                "/new - Регистрация пользователя")
                ),
                "/echo", new EchoAction("/echo"),
                "/new", new RegAction()
        );
        tg.registerBot(new BotMenu(actions, config.getProperty("bot.name"), config.getProperty("bot.key")));
    }

}
```

**Place**

```
package com.example.botv2;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "LocationList")
public class Place {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String monument, town, oblast, address, autor;



    public Place(String monument, String town, String oblast, String address, String name) {
        this.monument = monument;
        this.town = town;
        this.oblast = oblast;
        this.address = address;
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public Place() {

    }

    public String getMonument() {
        return monument;
    }

    public void setMonument(String monument) {
        this.monument = monument;
    }

    public String getTown() {
        return town;
    }

    public void setTown(String town) {
        this.town = town;
    }

    public String getOblast() {
        return oblast;
    }

    public void setOblast(String oblast) {
        this.oblast = oblast;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAutor(String name) {
        return autor;
    }

    public void setAutor(String autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

**PlaceRepo**

```
package com.example.botv2.repository;

import com.example.botv2.Place;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public interface PlaceRepo extends CrudRepository<Place, Long> {
}
```

The class through which the process of adding data to the database should take place

**RegAction**

```
package com.example.botv2;

import com.example.botv2.repository.PlaceRepo;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.BotApiMethod;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.ReplyKeyboardMarkup;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.KeyboardButton;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.KeyboardRow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RegAction implements Action {
  @Autowired
    private  PlaceRepo placeRepo;

    private enum RegistrationStage {
        LOCATION, TOWN, ADDRESS, OBLAST,COMPLETED
    }
    private final List<String> oblastList = List.of("Вінницька", "Волинська", "Дніпропетровська", "Донецька", "Житомирська", "Закарпатська", "Запорізька", "Івано-Франківська", "Київська", "Кіровоградська", "Луганська", "Львівська", "Миколаївська", "Одеська", "Полтавська", "Рівненська", "Сумська", "Тернопільська", "Харківська", "Херсонська", "Хмельницька", "Черкаська", "Чернівецька", "Чернігівська");
    private RegistrationStage currentStage = RegistrationStage.LOCATION;

    @Override
    public BotApiMethod handle(Update update) {
        var msg = update.getMessage();
        var chatId = msg.getChatId().toString();
        String text;


        switch (currentStage) {
            case LOCATION:
                text = "Розпочнемо додавання нової туристичної локації. Для успішного виконання слідуйте підказкам до отримання фрази (Реєстрація завершена. Дякую!)." +
                        " Розпочнемо з назви місця. Введіть найбільш підходящю назву";
                break;
            case TOWN:
                text = "Тепер введіть місто в якому знаходиться локація:";
                break;
            case ADDRESS:
                text = "Напишіть адресу в якій знаходиться локація:";
                break;
            case OBLAST:
                text = "Виберіть область, в якій знаходиться локація:";
                var replyKeyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
                replyKeyboardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
                replyKeyboardMarkup.setSelective(true); // Робимо клавіатуру вибору області вибірковою

                var keyboard = new ArrayList<KeyboardRow>();

                // Додаємо кнопки з областями
                for (String oblast : oblastList) {
                    KeyboardRow keyboardRow = new KeyboardRow();
                    KeyboardButton button = new KeyboardButton();
                    button.setText(oblast);
                    keyboardRow.add(button);
                    keyboard.add(keyboardRow);
                }

                replyKeyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);

                SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
                message.setChatId(chatId);
                message.setText(text);
                message.setReplyMarkup(replyKeyboardMarkup);

                break;
            default:
                text = "Дякую за увагу";
                resetState(); // Скидання стану на початковий
                break;
        }

        return new SendMessage(chatId, text);
    }
    private long chatId;
    private String placeName;
    private String town;
    private String oblast;
    private String address;
    private String name;
    @Override
    public BotApiMethod callback(Update update) {
        var msg = update.getMessage();
        var chatId = msg.getChatId().toString();
        var userInput = msg.getText();
        String text;

        switch (currentStage) {
            case LOCATION:
                placeName = userInput;
                System.out.println("Конструктор:"+"LOCATION: "+placeName);
                currentStage = RegistrationStage.TOWN;
                text = "Ви обрали назву місця: " + userInput + "\n Натисніть на /new для продовження додавання";
                break;
            case TOWN:
                town = userInput;
                currentStage = RegistrationStage.ADDRESS;
                text = "місто успішно додано: " + userInput + "\n Натисніть на /new для продовження додавання";
                break;
            case ADDRESS:
                address = userInput;
                currentStage = RegistrationStage.OBLAST;
                text = "Адреса успішно додано: " + userInput + "\n Залишилось зовсім трішечки, натисніть на /new для продовження ";
                break;
            case OBLAST:
                oblast = userInput;
                currentStage = RegistrationStage.COMPLETED;
                text = "Область успішно додано: " + userInput + "\n Ще трохи, натисніть на /new для ЗАВЕРШЕННЯ реєстрації";
                name = update.getMessage().getChat().getFirstName();

                System.out.println("Конструктор:"+"LOCATION: "+placeName+" " +
                        "TOWN: "+town+" OBLAST: "+oblast+" ADDRESS: "+address+" USERNAME: "+name);
                Place place = new Place(placeName, town, oblast,address,name);
                placeRepo.save(place);
                break;
            default:

                text = "Реєстрація завершена. Дякую!";
                resetState(); // Скидання стану на початковий
                break;
        }

        return new SendMessage(chatId, text);
    }
    private void resetState() {
        currentStage = RegistrationStage.LOCATION;
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
bot.name=****
bot.key=*************************

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/bot01
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=D04i03m20a03
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

And, if it matters, dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>BOTV2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>BOTV2</name>
    <description>BOTV2</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <telegram.version>5.6.0</telegram.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>${telegram.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MY SQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

please help to identify the error and point out the flaws in the code.

I tried to initialize placeRepo in RegAction, for example, by introducing a dependency with the creation of the PlaceRepo object through the Spring IoC mechanisms of the container (for example, using the @Autowired annotation). However, in this case, an error occurred in the Botv2Application class.

This Telegram bot needs to receive messages from the user and write them to the database. It receives the values, creates a constructor with the corresponding values, but the error occurs precisely when saving data through the repository:

```
ERROR 19052 --- [legram Executor] o.t.t.u.DefaultBotSession                : Cannot invoke "com.example.botv2.repository.PlaceRepo.save(Object)" because "this.placeRepo" is null

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.botv2.repository.PlaceRepo.save(Object)" because "this.placeRepo" is null
    at com.example.botv2.RegAction.callback(RegAction.java:119) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.botv2.BotMenu.onUpdateReceived(BotMenu.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27) ~[telegrambots-meta-5.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:317) ~[telegrambots-5.6.0.jar:na]
```

Comment: In your case `PlaceRepo` will be automatically scanned as it is with in the package of you main class `Botv2Application` and the  repo is extending from `CrudRepository`. So, can you try by either removing `@Component` on your repo or replace it with `@Repository` and also in `RegAction` use constructor injection, to do that just add `final`, i.e., `private  final PlaceRepo placeRepo;` and you can remove `@Autowired`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @kcsurapaneni. I followed the steps you suggested. However, in this case, there is an error in the Botv2Application class, we have to add parameters to new RegAction(), and in the future, we have to make a new class that imitates PlaceRepo, and after connecting it, the error will not disappear.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something or is there another way?

Comment: Do you mind creating a sample application with same config and pushing it to GitHub, so that I can take a look

Comment: This code is already on GitHub : https://github.com/Stigma7/BOT/tree/step2

Comment: In your situation, it appears that `BotMenu` is not managed by Spring IOC. Consequently, when `RegAction.callback()` is invoked, the `RegAction` object is manually instantiated. Therefore, even with the use of `@Autowired`, it won't be able to inject the `PlaceRepo`. I recommend reviewing how Spring manages bean dependencies for a better understanding.